# Serve multiple ports from Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, http, https

Is it possible for an app on Google App Engine to listen on multiple ports? For example, I'm running an app in Go, and I'd like to use both `ListenAndServe` (the default HTTP server) and also `ListenAndServeTLS`. These listen on different ports. Will this work? Will GAE allow me to listen on multiple port sockets, or will it prevent one from listening? Further, if I want to only run *one* listener, can I do that on a non-standard port (other than 80)?

Comment: You can't listen on any port.  Read the docs on the limitations of the platform.  http requests are sent to your application through standard apis.

Answer (score 4):

You should use Compute Engine or Managed VM for this.
As @Tim Hofman mentioned it's not possible on app engine.

From [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/):

> You cannot create a listen socket; you can only create outbound
>   sockets.